# Как в PHPStorm в js файлы добавить пробел перед слешем компонента react типа <Footer/>?

Tags: reactjs, phpstorm

Помогите, пожалуйста, не могу найти инфу как добавить пробел перед закрывающим слешем в компоненты react в PHPStorm?

сейчас так: `<Footer/>`
а надо: `<Footer />`

Comment: Собственно, а зачем?

Comment: тимлид сказал, чтобы стиль кода у команды соответствовал

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того чтобы добавить пробел перед закрывающим тегом в компонентах react, как того требует eslint
Нужно зайти:
Settings | Editor | Code Style | HTML |

Перейти во вкладу Other

И поставить галку в чекбокс - In empty tag

[image: вид в php storm]

Answer (score 0):

в webstorm 2020 можно это и тут найти - левой кнопкой на указание пробелов и выскачет это меню

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]